# Deserializing json values into a list

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing, json.net

Well I've been through multiple questions now about the same thing, still cant understand how the Newtonsoft works completely.

The response from the web page is,

```
{"status":[{"domain":"test.com","zone":"com","status":"active","summary":"active"}]}
```

I have the class made for parsing,

```
    public class Status
{
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string zone { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
}
```

And the DeserializeObject

```
IList<Status> domains = new List<Status>();
domains = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Status>>(src);
```

but it still doesn't want to execute the DeserializeObject, it keeps returning the error,

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Domain_Checker.Status]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Hey @Ale see if the solution provided by me has helped you. Please acknowledge if you still face any issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your json, you need a root object

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Status> Status {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(src);
```

Comment: Also, rename `name` by `domain`

Answer (score 0):

There is already answer how to parse this json to your own object. If you don't need that you can convert json to JObject. From JObject you can retrieve any value you want like this:

```
var json = {"status":[{"domain":"test.com","zone":"com","status":"active","summary":"active"}]};

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var jsonProperty = jsonObject["status"][0]["domain"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For deseralizing the JSON you need the class structure like this

```
public class Status
{
    [JsonProperty("domain")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("zone")]
    public string zone { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string summary { get; set; }
}

public class ClsStatus
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public List<Status> status { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you closely have a look at `[JsonProperty("domain")] public string name { get; set; }` I have used the name instead of domain. but still the deseralization will be done because of `JsonProperty`.

Just Deserialize it comfortably like.

```
string jsonstr = File.ReadAllText("YourJSONFile");
ClsStatus csObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsStatus>(JsonStr);
```